# Browserify transform plugin for evaluate IIFE and replace by its result during bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Well, i guess what I want is a bit advanced, let me explain:

The [brfs](https://github.com/browserify/brfs) transform plugin, for instance, replaces every call to fs.readFileSync into the actual contents of the target file. It gets replaced during the browserify bundle process.

I'm looking for a similar thing, but instead of replacing a call to an native function, I want it to run some IIFE through node context and replace its code inline by its result.

Example:

```
let slideList = (
    function thatWillBeRunIntoBrowserify(){ 
        return fs.readdirSync(__dirname); //__dirname, in this context, is the directory of this file, ie: the file where this code is written.
    })();
let anotherExample = (function thatAlsoWillBeRunIntoBrowserify(){ return Math.PI * 20 * 20; })();
```

Before bundle, i wish it transformed into:

```
let slideList = ["frontpage.svg", "preface.svg", "credits.svg", "other files into the folder..."];
let anotherExample = 1256.6370614359173;
```

Is there any transform plugin to do this, or something like?

**Edit:** The aforesaid code is part of more code, it's inside a Node.js module that returns a function, and inside this function, there will be either IIFEs that I wish to be run into client (browser) and IIFEs that shall be run during browserify bundle. The prepack.io has a third-party Browserify module (prepackify), however, as far as I tested it, it actually messes with the whole code. The entire code but specific IIFEs should be intact.

Comment: Yes, https://prepack.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepack

which will turn:

```
let anotherExample = (function thatAlsoWillBeRunIntoBrowserify(){ return Math.PI * 20 * 20; })();
```

or just

```
let anotherExample = Math.PI * 20 * 20;
```

Into

```
let anotherExample = 1256.6370614359173;
```

try it here: https://prepack.io/repl.html#OYGw9gRghiB0UDswBcAWBTATgUQB5QFsAHEdAAgF4yyBZKNWABQEkyAqMgJgAZ2vuA3EA

Comment: As far as I tested, it messes with the whole code, not only with the Inline code.

For instance, I have some node.js module defined as:

    "use strict";
    
    module.exports = exports = function(){
        console.log(`Generating slides...`);
        let slideList = (function thatIWant2BeRun(){ return fs.readdirSync(__dirname); })();
        slideList.forEach(slide=>{
        ... some WIP code follows
        });
    }

It transforms the whole module into an IIFE and doesn't resolve the actual IIFEs inside it.